# C++: no matching function call for constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, syntax-error

Here is the declaration of the constructor I'm using:

```
_Task Multiplier {
    int **Z;
    int **X;
    int **Y;
    int xr, xcols_yrows, yc;
    void main() {
        for( int i = 0; i < xcols_yrows; i++ ) {
            matrixmultiply(Z, X, xr, i, Y, yc);
        }
    }

  public:
    Multiplier( int *Z[], int *X[], int *Y[], int xr, int xcols_yrows, int yc) :
        Z( Z ), X( X ), Y( Y ), xr( xr ), xcols_yrows( xcols_yrows ), yc( yc ) {}

};
```

And here is where it is used:

```
int xrows, xcols_yrows, ycols;
// [cols][rows]
int X[xrows][xcols_yrows], Y[xcols_yrows][ycols], Z[xrows][ycols];
// start threads to multiply rows
Multiplier *multipliers[xrows];
for( int r = 0; r < xrows; r++ ) {
    multipliers[r] = new Multiplier( &Z, &X, &Y, r, xcols_yrows, ycols );
}
```

(they are all initialized)
But I get this weird error:

```
q3.cc: In member function 'virtual void uMain::main()':
q3.cc:132: error: no matching function for call to 'Multiplier::Multiplier(int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)xrows) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)ycols) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)], int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)xrows) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)xcols_yrows) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)], int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)xcols_yrows) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)ycols) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)], int&, int&, int&)'
q3.cc:37: note: candidates are: Multiplier::Multiplier(int**, int**, int**, int, int, int, UPP::uAction)
q3.cc:26: note:                 Multiplier::Multiplier(Multiplier&)
make: *** [q3.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The signature has a 7th parameter (see candidates). Are you sure everything is synced up?

Comment: yes, that is not the issue. we are using an extension of C++ called uC++, but the syntax i have there is the same as we learned. i also tried taking the '&'s away from Z, X, and Y, but still a nogo. it must be something with those arrays...

Comment: Well, for starters, the arrays you pass are two-dimensional. To wit, you're passing a (*)[int][int], not a **int. Can't test here, but what does something like &(&(Z[0][0])) do?

Comment: hrm... is the constructor not matching the two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: What language is this (or what compiler extensions are you using)? You cannot have variable length arrays in C++, and there is no such thing as `_Task` either.

Comment: See above. Sorry, still editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function parameters `X`, `Y` and `Z` basically expect a `array of pointers to int`, but you're giving it a `pointer to an array of arrays of int`.

Specifying a parameter as an array (declared with `[]`) decays to declaring a parameter as a pointer. And this is ok, as an array variable can be basically treated as a pointer to the first element of the array.

This is not valid for n-dimensional arrays, though, as the compiler needs to know how wide the array is along the second dimension in order to calculate the start of the next element along the first dimension... that is, in order to know what location in memory `X[1][0]` refers to, the compiler needs to know how many elements are in `X[0]`.

One solution would be to use a pointer to the start of each matrix, and do the address calculations yourself. Such as:

```
Multiplier( int *Z, int *X, int *Y, int xr, int xcols_yrows, int yc) :
    Z( Z ), X( X ), Y( Y ), xr( xr ), xcols_yrows( xcols_yrows ), yc( yc ) {}
// ...
multipliers[r] = new Multiplier( &Z[0][0], &X[0][0], &Y[0][0], r, xcols_yrows, ycols );
```

And know that `X[i][j]` in the calling code is actually `X[i*xcols_yrows+j]` inside `Multiplier`.

Comment: :) i'm used to PHP. never thought multidimensional arrays would be that much of a bitch, but thanks a lot for your help. my teacher must be crazy to think that this was a '10 minute question'.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter declaration `int *Z[]` specifies an array of pointers to integers. The member declaration `int **Z` specifies a pointer to a pointer (or array thereof). The argument type `int X[xrows][xcols_yrows]` is a multidimensional array with no pointers at all.

Furthermore, the allocated storage is on the stack, where it will disappear after the `return` statement. Since the Multiplier object is allocated with `new`, presumably the array should have a similar lifetime. Probably the array should be allocated by `new` in `Multiplier::Multiplier`, or in any case it should be a managed by a `unique_ptr` or `auto_ptr` object.

There are several solutions to the first problem:

1. Use a templated constructor which detects the dimensions of the array at compile time.
2. Use an array of pointers allocated by `new` or `calloc`.
3. Allocate a one-dimensional array and use it in a multidimensional fashion.